# Bonjour network

Tags: ios, networking, bonjour

I am new to Bonjour network.
Is there any way to create mirror application with bonjour network where user can share screen from one ipad to another ipad and interact with it?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Apple example which used Bonjour network and might be reach your requirements. Just download and run the sample (need two devices)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply...I will check the sample code.